# Can Coefficient of Variation be used to verify the representativeness of the mean?

Tags: standard-deviation, mean, coefficient-of-variation

I have a sample with approximately 45 million elements, with 4,410 as the mean and 1,657 as the standard deviation.

I am not confident whether or not the mean well represents the sample due to the dispersion presented in the standard deviation. Thus, I found another descriptive statistic, named coefficient of variation, that when it's between zero and one means that the sample has low dispersion and mean can be used as a good representative of the sample. However, it was in an informal source.

Does anyone agree with that approach and/or have a source that well explains this use of the coefficient of variation?

Comment: Coefficient of variation is standard deviation/mean. The only way it can be negative is if the mean is negative, not so here. In practice it is only useful (some say: only defined) if all values are positive. Either your source is unreliable or you copied it incorrectly. All that said, for your problem the coefficient of variation is unlikely to add any useful information to what you know. The main question over whether to use the mean is whether the distribution is skewed and some other summary statistics might also be useful (e.g. the median).

Comment: You tagged this "coefficient-of-variation". Several threads in this forum discuss appropriate uses, which is why I gave only a brief comment.

Comment: sorry, I made a mistake explaining the coefficient of variation. Where you saw "below zero", I mean "between 0 and 1". Already changed in the post.

By the way, the median of my sample is 3578, and there's no negative value on it.

How can I measure skewedness of the distribution, and how to decide if the mean well represent or not the sample?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Whether the mean represents the sample well is not reducible to a yes or no answer. Whether to cite the mean is a practical decision, so what is the context? What could go wrong for you if you used the mean? Why should you just use the mean when you have other information? Skewness is a standard topic: see (e.g.) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness for an introduction. But as the median and the mean look quite different you might need, at a minimum, to cite both.

Comment: That's a pretty large "sample"...  If you've got 45 million data points, there are probably a lot of other questions you should be asking of your data than whether 2 numbers is an adequate summarisation...

Answer (score 2):

The coefficient of variation doesn't help here. It only shows whether there is a lot of spread.

The mean can never "represent the sample"; the question is whether it is a good representation of the central tendency of the sample. But there are many things that can make mean a poor choice, e.g.:

1. Outliers
2. Skew
3. If the data are rates
4. Multimodality